# Make a one sequence if possible

Tags: c++, algorithm

A sequence of integers is a one- sequence if the difference between any two consecutive numbers in this sequence is -1 or 1 and its first element is 0.

More precisely: a1, a2, ..., an is a one-sequence if:

```
For any k (1 ≤  k < n): |a[k] - a[k+1]|=1, 
a[1]=0
```

Given n and s ─ sum of all elements in a. W need to construct a one-sequence with the given parameters.

Like If n=8 and s=4 then one of such sequence is [0 1 2 1 0 -1 0 1].

Note if for given n and s we cant form such sequence than also we need to tell that its not possible.Otherwise we need to tell any of such one sequence.How to do this problem Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to solve it yourself?

Comment: @aioobe Yeah i tried to solve by making it with help of 1,0,-1,2 and trying to place at each position one of the four numbers.But problem is we need to make sum equal to S also

Comment: You should post this as a coding challenge at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.   There will be more cunning answers than you can poke a stick at, in no time.   Just make sure to phrase the question as a code golf question ;)

Comment: @GreenAsJade I dont want any code or so.I just want an correct algorithm or a hint to do it

Comment: Hint: use dynamic programming and memoization.

Comment: @Kevin, I don't think that's even necessary.

Comment: @Kevin How its going to help?Please provide some more explanation

Comment: It wouldn't be a hint if I explained the whole thing ;-)

Comment: @Kevin Hahaha...Very funny.But i would love to learn it by Dynammic programming

Comment: Regarding your edit: Put solve in a separate function and let it return a list (as I've shown in my pseudo code). As it stands now, you'll execute the `push_back` in the reverse order (since the innermost call will return before the first call).

Comment: @aioobe I didnt get you.

Comment: You're actually really close to a working solution. Peek at [my Java solution](http://ideone.com/2m1X0p) if you feel like it.

Comment: Please don't include the answer in the question. Instead, ask clarifications with a comment at the bottom of the answer itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another take on aioobe's algorithm, with a formal proof of correctness.

Given a sequence a(k), define the difference sequence d(k) = a(k+1) - a(k) and observe that a(1) + a(2) + ... + a(n) = (n-1)d(1) + (n-2)d(2) + ... + 1d(n-1).

**Theorem:** for parameters n and s, there exists a length-n one-sequence summing to s if and only if (1) n(n-1)/2 mod 2 = s mod 2 and (2) |s| ≤ n(n-1)/2.

**Proof:** by induction on n. The base case, n = 1, is trivial. Inductively, since d(k) ∈ {±1}, we observe that both (1) and (2) are necessary conditions, as n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1 = n(n-1)/2 and -1 mod 2 = 1 mod 2. Conversely, assume both (1) and (2). If s ≥ 0, then construct a length-(n-1) sequence summing to s - (n-1). If s < 0, then construct a length-(n-1) sequence summing to s + (n-1). Both (1) and (2) are satisfied for these constructions (some tedious case analysis omitted), so it follows from the inductive hypothesis that they succeed. Increase/decrease the elements of this sequence by one depending on whether s ≥ 0/s < 0 and put 0 at the beginning.

Since the proof of the theorem is constructive, we can implement it in Python.

```py
def oneseq(n, s):
    assert isinstance(n, int)
    assert isinstance(s, int)
    nchoose2 = n*(n-1)//2
    abss = abs(s)
    if n < 1 or abss%2 != nchoose2%2 or abss > nchoose2: return None
    a = [0]
    for k in range(n-1, 0, -1):  # n-1, n-2, ..., 1
        d = 1 if s >= 0 else -1
        a.append(a[-1] + d)  # a[-1] equivalent to a[len(a) - 1]
        s -= k*d
    return a
```

Comment: What you mean by a.append(a[-1] + x) ??Are you sure "-1" ??

Comment: @typedef Yes, that means last element.

Comment: Its tooo difficult to understand this code of python..:(..But am trying

Comment: @typedef You need to set `int x = n*(n-1)/2;` (divide by 2) and return 0 for failure, otherwise yes.

Answer (score 2):

First, to decide if it's possible to solve or not can be done up front. Since you go either +1 or -1 in each step, you'll go from even, to odd, to even, to odd... So with an odd value for *n* you'll only be able to reach an even number, and for an even value of *n* you'll only be able to reach an odd number. The reachable *range* is simple as well: ±(1+2+3+...+n).

Second, if you draw the "decision tree" on whether to go up (+1) or down (-1) in each step, and draw the accumulated sum in each node, you'll see that you can do a kind of binary search to find the sum at one of the leaves in the tree.

You go +1 if you're about to undershoot, and go -1 if you're about to overshoot. The tricky part is to figure out if you're going to undershoot/overshoot. Your current "state" should be computed by

"what I have so far" + "what I'll get for free by staying at this level for the rest of the array".

What you have "for free by staying at this level" is `stepsLeft * previousValue`.

Here's some pseudo code.

```
solve(stepsLeft, prev, acc) {
    if stepsLeft == 0, return empty list  // base case
    ifIStayHere = acc + prev*stepsLeft
    step = ifIstayHere > s ? prev-1 : prev+1
    return [step] concatenated by solve(stepsLeft-1, step, acc+step)
}
```

Note that this solution does not include the initial 0, so call it with `stepsLeft = n-1`.

As you can see, it's θ(n) and it works for all cases I've tested. (Implemented it in Java.)

Comment: For N<=10000.So at their can be maximum of 2^n leaves which  think its pretty inefficient.

Comment: Not if you do a binary search.

Comment: How binary search ?Am not getting you.Also you mean if n is even then s also need to be even and vice versa?

Comment: Suppose your input is `n=5`, `s=4` and you've come this far: `[0,1,2,_,_]`. Now if you (hypothetically now) *stay* at `2`: `[0,1,2,2,2]` you'll over shoot, because you'll end up with sum=7. So you go downward in the next step: `[0,1,2,1,_]`. And from there on you recurse.

Comment: Can i see your java code ?As i doubt about its complexity

Comment: *"I dont want any code or so.I just want an correct algorithm or a hint to do it"* :-) I can give you the solution for `n=1000`, `s=123456`: http://aoeu.se/so/sol.txt  Had it been an exponential solution my computer would have been working a couple of more years ;-)

Comment: Your link does not seem to work

Comment: Changed to another link.

Comment: Then i must be implementing it in wrong way

Comment: What are values of other two parameters at time of calling ?

Comment: You start at `0` so `prev=0` and your accumulated sum when you start is `0` so `acc=0`.

Comment: @aioobe Can you please look at my edited post

Comment: "You go +1 if you're about to undershoot, and go -1 if you're about to overshoot." This doesn't sound right. This way you choose an arbitrary subset of all possible sequences.

Comment: @aioobe See this code also doesnt seem to work. http://pastebin.com/GnEBanZ3

Comment: @Sofffia, so give me a counter example. The "overshoot/undershoot" explanation is a very informal description of the algorithm. But I guarantee you that it works.

Comment: @typedef, I'm not so good with C++ but it looks like a return statement is missing.

Comment: @aioobe What about `[-1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1]` for `n = 8` and `s = 2`?

Comment: That sequence can't be produced by my program. The task is not to recognize all valid sequences, but to *generate one* valid sequence.